# How to expand or collapse a cell in gridView ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridView and a columns.
The cols are `<asp:boundfield>`, which I fill with a data from the server using databind().
This is what I have so far:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvMichtavim" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowStyle-CssClass="row1"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="row2" ClientIDMode="Static" HeaderStyle-CssClass="table_title"
    Width="100%" class="table_title" ScrollBars="Auto" RowStyle-Height="30px" HeaderStyle-Height="20px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="row2" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:ButtonField HeaderText="watch Pdf" CommandName="Select" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"
            ButtonType="Image" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" ControlStyle-CssClass="adobe_pdf"></asp:ButtonField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IchzurYeshutNimaan" HeaderText="idNum" DataFormatString="{0:000000000}"
            HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
            ItemStyle-Width="100px" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IchzurShemNimaan" HeaderText="full Name" HeaderStyle-Width="200px" ItemStyle-Width="200px"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IchzurNadonMichtav" HeaderText="Subject" HeaderStyle-Width="200px"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="table_title" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="row1" />
</asp:GridView>
```

When I fill the cols, If the data is very long, let say the subject is "payment for the hotel when you check in next week", it will expand the cell into 2 rows. (In picture)

[image: gridView with a cell that contain 2 rows]

I want to show only the first row and 2 dots ("payment for the hotel when you check.."), and when the user click on the row, it will expand the cell and show all the content
I guess I need javascript but I don't know where to start.
I thought maybe there is a way throw the asp options.

Thank you.

Comment: You can try apply css as explained at https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/ to the boundfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want with a Method in code behind and a little bit of `jQuery` and a small modification to the GridView. First add the Method to the code behind.

```
public string trimString(string input)
{
    int trimLength = 25;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) && input.Length > trimLength)
    {
        return string.Format("<div>{0}<span>... </span><span style=\"display:none\">{1}</span></div>", input.Substring(0, trimLength), input.Substring(trimLength, input.Length - trimLength));
    }
    else
    {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Then change the `BoundField` to a `TemplateField`.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# trimString(Eval("Subject").ToString()) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And finally the javascript function that will add a listener to the `<div>` items in the GridView that when clicked will hide the first `<span>` and show the second one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= GridView1.ClientID %> div').click(function () {
            $(this).find("span:nth-child(1)").hide();
            $(this).find("span:nth-child(2)").show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [css ellipsis styling](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) and place the field data in both the `Text` and `ToolTip` properties.  I'm not a fan of cell animation in gridviews.  It's looks slick, but it's distracting to the eye for users that need to see this data continually.

```
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block
}
```

---

You still need to convert the `BoundField` to a `Template` as BoundFields do not give you access to the `ToolTip` property

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="lblSubject" 
               CssClass="truncate" 
               Text='<%# Eval("IchzurNadonMichtav") %>' 
               ToolTip='<%# Eval("IchzurNadonMichtav") %>'>
    </asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

---

### See it in action:

Keep in mind that you are styling the rendered results, not the asp markup.

```css
table {
  width:500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.truncate {
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>xxx</td>
    <td>
      <span id="some_id" 
            class="truncate" 
            title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et tortor ultricies, volutpat neque at, dictum arcu. Nam dictum, enim vitae ultricies consectetur, justo quam consectetur ligula, eget lobortis nisi lectus in elit. Aenean enim nisl, lacinia sit amet neque eu, feugiat porttitor mauris. Proin neque enim, vulputate sed libero">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et tortor ultricies, volutpat neque at, dictum arcu. Nam dictum, enim vitae ultricies consectetur, justo quam consectetur ligula, eget lobortis nisi lectus in elit. Aenean enim nisl, lacinia sit amet neque eu, feugiat porttitor mauris. Proin neque enim, vulputate sed libero
      </span>
    </td>
    <td>xxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```